# Delay A Javascript function between a POST and a GET request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to delay the GET request from the POST. Basically, with this code, my backend server send the response as a JSON array before it computed the POST request. I'd like my server to handle the POST request first, and with a five second delay, call the GET request.

(For your information, this code put the content of an HTML form in a Django db and then request all the content from this DB and display it on an HTML page.  This is where the problem is, because when a user submit the form, he will have all the content from the DB without his last sent because the 'screenshot' of the DB was taken before the server put his submit).

```
$(document).on('submit','#post-form',function(e){
    clearInterval(loop)
    e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/send',
        data:{
            room_name:$('#room_name').val(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function(data){
           //alert(data)
        }
      });
      document.getElementById('room_name').value = ''
  $(document).ready(function com() {
  function imgMarkup(model) {
  if (model.media) {//mediasrc
    return `<img class='imgchat' src=${window.location.origin}/static/${model.mediasrc}.png>`
  }
  return '';
}
function csvMarkup(model) {
  if (model.excel) {
    return `<p><a href="${window.location.origin}/static/${model.mediasrc}" class="dl-csv">[Download]</a></p>`
  }
  return '';
}
function botCheck(model) {
  if (model.bot) {
    return 'FinanceUIp.png'
  }
  return 'Y.png';
}
  loop = setTimeout(setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/trafic",
      success: function check(response) {
        //CODE WORKSPACE //


        }

        //CODE  checkview //

      },
      error: function(response){
        //setTimeout(clearInterval(loop),10000)
      }
    });
  }, 1000), 5000)
})
  });
```

I tried the setTimeout function but it does not work. Like there is no delay at all.

Comment: `setTimeout(setInterval(function() {` just doesn't seem like something you would want to do.   Just `loop = setInterval(function() {` seems to be enough as you have a `clearInterval(loop)` elsewhere.

Comment: `setTimeout(setInterval(function() {` - setTimeout expects a callback, but you're passing the result of `setInterval` to `setTimeout` - so the setInterval runs immediately in order to get the function callback, but setInterval doesn't provided a function callback

Comment: It the same as `var x = setInterval(..., 1000); loop = setTimeout(x, 5000)` - which should be clearer why the `setInterval` runs immediately and ignores the setTimeout.

Comment: Yes I agree, But my final goal is to add delay to the GET function.

Comment: `loop = setTimeout(setInterval(function() {` -> `setTimeout(function() { loop = setInterval(function()...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example snippet (you can run it) that you can adapt to your use case.

- An endless get request loop starts.
- When a post request is made, the get request loop is stopped.
- When the post request is done (or fails in this case), the get request loop starts.
- etc.

As a suggestion though, using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) would save you a lot of headaches as it provides easy chaining between actions.

```js
let getLoop;

function stopGetRequestLoop() {
  console.log(`*********\nGet loop stops`);
  clearInterval(getLoop)
}

function getRequestLoop() {
  console.log(`*********\nGet loop starts`);
  const start = Date.now();
  getLoop = setInterval(() => {
    // the actual get operation
    const end = Date.now();
    console.log(`Request made after ${end - start}ms`);
  }, 1000);
}

const postRequest = () => {
  stopGetRequestLoop()
  console.log(`*********\nPost request starts`);
  fetch("/")
    // This specific request fails so catch is used. But you can use then or finally
    .catch((e) => {
      // This delay is just a simulation of a post request delay, you can either ignore it or use it if you need a timeout.
      const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000;
      console.log(`> The get request will resume in ${delay}ms`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        getRequestLoop();
      }, delay);
    });
};

getRequestLoop();

document.getElementById("start-button").addEventListener("click", getRequestLoop);
document.getElementById("post-button").addEventListener("click", postRequest);
document.getElementById("stop-button").addEventListener("click", stopGetRequestLoop);
```

```html
<button id="start-button">Start get request loop</button>
<button id="stop-button">Stop get request loop</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="post-button">Make a post request</button>
```